# Searching Local Eml Files via MimeKit

Tags: c#, email, search, mailkit, mimekit

I am trying to read, show and search EML files with attachments downloaded on my computer. To do that; I am using MimeKit v2.1.0. It's okay when I read and show the files with using MimeMessage. However, I have many messages and need to be able to search with a few words. As i understand, MimeKit has no search option. What can be able to do that is MailKit but this time, I could not read local EML files. I have searched for couple days to find a solution but returned with empty hands.

So, to sum up, I am looking for a way either search with MimeKit or read local EML files with MailKit. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Couple of thoughts: eml is a text format. You could search inside them just with any tool that allows searching in text files. Alternative, you could parse out what you want to search from them and out it in a structured repository of some kind (eg a database, a search index etc) and search that.

Comment: What fields of the messages do you want to search? Subject? From? text body? What?

Comment: Actually all fields. For example, if one wants to search 'apple', I need to find it wherever it is, no matter if it is in subject, body or attachments. For now I can do it in all fields except attachments as you advised. I will look forward to find a way to search it in attachs too without copying them into distinct files. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MailKit's search APIs are for IMAP. Granted, someone could implement the IMailFolder interface for local messages (in mbox or Maildir format?), but that has not been done by anyone afaik.

That said, you can do this:

```
static bool Search (string fileName, string text)
{
    var message = MimeMessage.Load (fileName);
    var body = message.TextBody;

    return body != null && body.Contains (text);
}
```